# AdMob general event tracking

Tags: android, admob

This question might sound a bit silly, but I heard that AdMob can track general events in an mobile app, not only clicking on adds or so (like clicking on a button). I did a search on the Internet but didn't find anything relevant. I was wondering if it's related to AdMob API or AdMob SDK and what could be the difference between them. Also, a start point could come in great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like [Google Analytics for Mobile Apps](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/). The AdMob SDK only really tracks impressions and clicks. There is no longer an AdMob API for publishers to get ads for mobile websites (they should use AdSense), only an AdMob API for Ads, but that is for advertisers building ads on AdMob.